# Deserialize data into protobuf class

Tags: c#, mongodb, xml-serialization, protocol-buffers

I am trying to deserialize data from Mongodb to MyClass that has been created by protoc (version 3).

I am using MongoDB.Driver (version 4)
BsonSerializer.Deserialize(result, MyClass.GetType());
Which uses XmlSerializer to deserialize the data.

The problem lies in how protobuf represents its collections.
A List is created as Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField
with **no setter**. XmlSerializer cannot deserialize fields with no setters.
How can I solve this problem in a way that it doesn't become an ugly hack?

Options I have come up with:

1. Create my own Serializer that MongoDB can use to handle properties with no setter.
2. Create my own class generator that adds a public setter.
3. Create a new class as a mapper between MongoDB's serialized data and protobufs class.

Option 1 seems daunting, option 2 makes me create a new fork, which is a pain to maintain. Option 3 is the easiest by far, but also messy, I'd prefer not to create another layer of complexity if there are better ways to deal with this.

So my question is:

Is there any other ways to solve this problem? Is there anything I am missing that is already built-in or maybe I am missing something trivial?

Edit:
This is a snippet of what is getting generated by protoc verison 3:

```
/// <summary>Field number for the "Recipients" field.</summary>
public const int RecipientsFieldNumber = 5;
private static readonly pb::FieldCodec<string> _repeated_recipients_codec = 
    pb::FieldCodec.ForString(42);
private readonly pbc::RepeatedField<string> recipients_ = new   pbc::RepeatedField<string>();
public pbc::RepeatedField<string> Recipients {
  get { return recipients_; }
}
```

It comes from this proto-file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package DataModels.Data;

message MailTemplateMessage {
    string UUID = 1;
    string SubjectLine = 2; 
    string Body = 3;
    string Sender = 4;
    repeated string Recipients = 5;
}
```

Comment: "XmlSerializer cannot deserialize fields with no setters." - that's just not true; as long as `XmlSerializer` can identify that it is a list-like class, it works perfectly fine without a setter. It may of course be that `RepeatedField` isn't list-like enough for `XmlSerializer` to be convinced! However; how complicated is your model? Does it use .proto schema v3 features? The reason I ask: protobuf-net is a parallel implementation of protobuf on .net, and is designed to work well in idiomatic .net scenarios like this; classes can be hand-coded, or there is a code-gen tool, but no .proto v3.

Comment: (by which I mean, no .proto v3 *at the schema definition level*; in terms of what is actually on the wire, there is no change is v3 - so a v3 schema *can* be processed just fine by protobuf-net; but the codegen bits won't like it)

Comment: I see, maybe It's just not supported in the MongoDB.Driver since the code will skip fields with no setter. I am using the Any syntax quite extensively, which is a version 3 feature. How does XmlSerializer fair with readonly collections?

Comment: I would expect it to struggle, to be honest

Comment: I see, so even if I manage to fix the issue with no setter in the MongoDB.Driver I still will have problems with the fact that protobuf creates collections with readonly. Do you have any suggestions of a approach? Right now some sort of mapper logic seems inevitable

Comment: Well, according to [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/collections/repeated-field-t-), `RepeatedField<T>` implements `IList<T>`, which should be more than enough to be usable by `XmlSerializer`, and suggests it is *not* readonly

Comment: I have included the code generation that shows that it gets the readonly flag without me adding anything to the proto-file.

Comment: the *field* is readonly, but the collection isn't; `XmlSerializer` is fine with that type of thing - it just calls `Add`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116500/discussion-between-user4319995-and-marc-gravell).